# Force dnf install yum

Tags: software-installation, yum, dnf

I have the problem with `dnf` that I cannot install `yum`.

```bash
dnf install yum
```

I want to be able to solve this problem in any way, it may be by deleting files, or making it detect files that are already present on the system as installed.

The packages appear installed in *dnf*, because they were installed from *another package manager*, or they already came in *another Linux (Puppy Linux)*, but those files are present. How do I make it install it by overwriting system files?

In English the error would be like the following:

```js
Running operation verification
Verification of successful operation.
Running test operations
The downloaded packages have been cached for the next transaction.
You can clear the cache packages by running 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction Test Error:
   /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6 file conflict between attempted installations of lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64
```

On:

```bash
LC_ALL=C dnf install yum
```

Log:

```js
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6 conflicts between attempted installs of lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/[ conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/arch conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/b2sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/base32 conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/base64 conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/basename conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/basenc conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/cat conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/chcon conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/chgrp conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/chmod conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/chown conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/chroot conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/cksum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/comm conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/coreutils conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/cp conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/csplit conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/cut conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/date conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/dd conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/df conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/dir conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/dircolors conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/dirname conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/du conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/echo conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/env conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/expand conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/expr conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/factor conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/false conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/fmt conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/fold conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/groups conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/head conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/hostid conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/id conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/install conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/join conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/link conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/ln conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/logname conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/ls conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/md5sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mkdir conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mkfifo conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mknod conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mktemp conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mv conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/nice conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/nl conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/nohup conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/nproc conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/numfmt conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/od conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/paste conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/pathchk conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/pinky conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/pr conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/printenv conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/printf conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/ptx conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/pwd conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/readlink conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/realpath conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/rm conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/rmdir conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/runcon conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/seq conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sha1sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sha224sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sha256sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sha384sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sha512sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/shred conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/shuf conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sleep conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sort conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/split conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/stat conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/stdbuf conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/stty conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sum conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/sync conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/tac conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/tail conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/tee conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/test conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/timeout conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/touch conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/tr conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/true conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/truncate conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/tsort conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/tty conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/uname conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/unexpand conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/uniq conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/unlink conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/users conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/vdir conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/wc conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/who conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/whoami conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/yes conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/chroot conflicts between attempted installs of coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64 and coreutils-9.0-4.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/capsh conflicts between attempted installs of libcap-utils-2.62-1.x86_64 and libcap-2.22-11.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/getcap conflicts between attempted installs of libcap-utils-2.62-1.x86_64 and libcap-2.22-11.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/getpcaps conflicts between attempted installs of libcap-utils-2.62-1.x86_64 and libcap-2.22-11.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/setcap conflicts between attempted installs of libcap-utils-2.62-1.x86_64 and libcap-2.22-11.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/tabset/stdcrt conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/tabset/vt100 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/c/cygwin conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/k/konsole conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/k/konsole-256color conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/l/linux conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/n/nxterm conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/p/putty conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/p/putty-256color conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/p/putty-vt100 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-cygwin conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-cygwin-native conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt100 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt100-am conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt102 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt200 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt220 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt52 conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-color conflicts between attempted installs of ncurses-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
  file /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 conflicts between attempted installs of xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64 and lib64lzma5-5.2.5-3.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 conflicts between attempted installs of lib64curl4-7.81.0-1.x86_64 and libcurl-7.29.0-59.el7.x86_64
  file /sbin/depmod conflicts between attempted installs of kmod-29-1.x86_64 and kmod-29-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/insmod conflicts between attempted installs of kmod-29-1.x86_64 and kmod-29-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/lsmod conflicts between attempted installs of kmod-29-1.x86_64 and kmod-29-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/modinfo conflicts between attempted installs of kmod-29-1.x86_64 and kmod-29-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/modprobe conflicts between attempted installs of kmod-29-1.x86_64 and kmod-29-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/rmmod conflicts between attempted installs of kmod-29-1.x86_64 and kmod-29-1.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/hardlink conflicts between attempted installs of util-linux-core-2.37.3-1.x86_64 and util-linux-core-2.37.3-1.x86_64
  file /etc/issue conflicts between attempted installs of util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64 and centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/clock conflicts between attempted installs of util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64 and util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/hwclock conflicts between attempted installs of util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64 and util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/pivot_root conflicts between attempted installs of util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64 and util-linux-2.37.3-1.x86_64
  file /lib/systemd/system-preset/85-display-manager.preset conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /lib/systemd/system-preset/90-default.preset conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.x86_64
  file /sbin/halt conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/poweroff conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/reboot conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /sbin/udevadm conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/systemctl conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/systemd-escape conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/udevadm conflicts between attempted installs of systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64 and systemd-249.20220113-1.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/chkconfig conflicts between attempted installs of chkconfig-1.15-2.x86_64 and chkconfig-1.15-2.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/service conflicts between attempted installs of chkconfig-1.15-2.x86_64 and chkconfig-1.15-2.x86_64
```

Comment: Please run `dnf` with `LC_ALL=C dnf` so that the errors are in English

Comment: @muru Ready, edited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to change **/etc/dnf/dnf.conf** so that only a single repository is active. For my case, *CentOS 7*, `enabled=1` and the others, `enabled=0`.

```ini
[main]
name=Open Mandriva Main
gpgcheck=False
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=False
best=False
skip_if_unavailable=True

[release]
name=Open Mandriva 4.3
baseurl=https://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/4.3/repository/x86_64/main/release/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0

[cooker]
name=Open Mandriva Cooker
clean_requirements_on_remove=False
best=False
skip_if_unavailable=True
baseurl=https://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/cooker/repository/x86_64/unsupported/release/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0

[centossiete]
name=CentOS 7
clean_requirements_on_remove=False
best=False
skip_if_unavailable=True
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```